# Can we pickle continuations in PyPy? How?

Tags: python, serialization, pypy, continuations

I am trying PyPy for the first time because I need serializable continuations. Specifically, this is what I am attempting:

```py
from _continuation import continulet
import pickle

def f(cont):
    cont.switch(111)
    cont.switch(222)
    cont.switch(333)

c = continulet(f)

print(c.switch())
print(c.switch())
saved = pickle.dumps(c)
```

When I try to pickle `c` I get this error, though: `NotImplementedError: continulet's pickle support is currently disabled`.

So, is there some way to enable pickling of continuations? The message suggests this, but so far I couldn't find out how.

Edit: I am using "PyPy 7.3.1 with GCC 9.3.0" (Python 3.6.9) on Linux.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://doc.pypy.org/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/), it's not supported. (See page 39)

Comment: @PeterWood This actually says "[Unimplemented features] Continuing execution of a continulet in a different thread (but if it is “simple enough”, you can pickle it andunpickle it in the other thread)." So, it should be possible if the continuation is "simple enough". Or did I misinterpret it?

Comment: It seems that pages 98ff of @PeterWood's document is devoted to the problems with pickling.